# Dynamic Typescript type based on picked values from an array of objects

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to create a dynamic type which is based on the values of a key of an array of objects:

```
type MeasureDeclaration = Array<{ name: string }>;

abstract class Decoder {
  public measures: MeasureDeclaration;

  addMeasure (measureName: T) {

  }
}

class TempDecoder extends Decoder {
  constructor () {
    super();

    this.measures = [
      { name: 'temperature' },
      { name: 'battery' },
    ];
  }
}

const tempDecoder = new TempDecoder();

// OK
tempDecoder.addMeasure('temperature');

// KO
tempDecoder.addMeasure('humidity');
```

In plain Javascript I would have done something like `measureName: MeasuresDeclaration.map(elem => elem.name)` but in Typescript I really struggle to understand how to achieve that.

Comment: Is the `measures` array of objects readonly? Or is it going to be manipulated so that you can add new entries to it? That's because an easy way out is to declare it `as const`, which allows mapping of its values to explicitly type very straightforward.

Comment: Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/m0AzqW) works for you ?

Comment: The `measures` array is readonly yes, how can you map values to types then? @captain-yossarian, unfortunately your proposal is not optimal because it require to declare manually the `LIST` type in addition to the actual `measures` array

Answer (score 0):

Someone gave me the answer (thanks Jean and Paul!)

```
type MeasureDeclaration<T = string> = ReadonlyArray<{ name: T }>;

class DecodedPayload<T extends Decoder> {
  public decoder: T;

  constructor(decoder: T) {
    this.decoder = decoder;
  }

  addMeasure(measureName: T["measures"][number]["name"]) {
    // ...
  }
}
abstract class Decoder {
  public measures: MeasureDeclaration = [];

  abstract decode (): DecodedPayload<Decoder>;
}

class TempDecoder extends Decoder {
  public measures = [
    { name: 'temperature' },
    { name: 'battery' },
  ] as const;

  constructor () {
    super();
  }

  decode (): DecodedPayload<Decoder> {
    const decodedPayload = new DecodedPayload<TempDecoder>(this);

    // OK
    decodedPayload.addMeasure('temperature');

    // @ts-expect-error
    decodedPayload.addMeasure('humidity');

    return decodedPayload;
  }
}
```